# Adding a menu-bar to the app's window

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I've been asked to add a menu bar to our ARC app's chrome window.  So, two questions:

- Is this possible?
- If so, how would one define and interact with it?

To clarify, this would be similar to the drop-down menu that the usual Chrome window has in the top-right corner but it would contain custom entries.

Comment: By chrome window do you mean where the minimize, exit and back-button go?

Comment: Is this an ARC app or a normal Chrome app? It may be mistagged

Comment: @Theyouthis: Yes, that's the location that's been suggested to me.

Comment: @ElijahTaylor: This is about an ARC app running on a Chromebook.

Comment: I would be surprised if you could do that. Good luck.

Comment: @Theyouthis: heh me too :)  But, I need to ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there's no way to add a menu button in the top bar. The functionality you're describing sounds similar to an action bar, which is the preferred way in Android to add a menu in the app (as an overflow list), since navigation bar menu keys are being phased out: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected as much.